# Unable to read cell color of an xls file using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls, hssf

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;


// Assume this method is wrapped in a class
public static void parseFile(){
    // File Path has a .xls extension
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    for(int rn = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); rn <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rn++){
        HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rn);

        for(int cn = 0; cn < row.getLastCellNum(); cn++){
            HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cn);
            //This is apache's color
            HSSFColor color = cell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColorColor; 

            // Excel entire row is red and it is not entering here.
            if(color.equals(IndexedColors.RED)){
                System.out.println("I made it here!");
                cn++;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The file is processing fine but it won't enter my "if statement". Am I doing it wrong? Can this be done with xls files? I see examples for xlsx but I don't see any for xls. Thanks!

Comment: print the Color cordinates to test after Color color object init, *may be, it not be RED!*

Comment: Upon debugging what `Color` instance do you get on the line Color `color = cell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColorColor; ` ?

Comment: System.out.println(color) returns "org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor@3ef96fb"

Answer (score 1):

The method `getFillBackgroundColorColor()` returns the following type :

```
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Color
```

not a

```
java.awt.Color
```

one way to check for RED is checking the RGB values, like so:

```
byte[] rgb=colore.getRGB();
System.out.println("color" + " " + rgb[0] + " " + rgb[1] + " " + rgb[2] );
if ( (rgb[0] == (byte)0xff) 
  && (rgb[1] == 0)
  && (rgb[2] == 0)) {
     System.out.println("that is totally red");
}
```

the main point is, do not mix up class `Color` of apachePOI  with  `java.awt.Color`

Comment: but then how do I use that object to see if it's red?